# Registration Form - Reject certain criteria and give a message back to the user

Tags: php

I'm trying to implement it where if the user is trying to create an account they must meet a certain string length ETC. If they don't then the page should be spitting a message out at them.

I tried the following for just username as a test, but it's rather unsuccessful. I've only been doing PHP for a couple days, have mercy I am new and I have scoured all over google, youtube, and stackoverflow and cannot seem to get it to work for my specific situation.

```
<?php 
include_once 'config.php';
$_SESSION['message'] = "Initiating Account Creation.";

$mysqli = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $conn_array) or die ($_SESSION['message'] = "No connection to the database.");

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    session_start();
    // No crazy special characters in user or email because it can mess with SQL query + inputs.
    $username = ($_POST['username']);
    $email = ($_POST['email']);
    //VERIFY TWO PASSWORDS ARE EQUAL.
    $password = ($_POST['password']);
    $password2 = ($_POST['confirmpassword']);

    $str_len1 = strlen(($_POST['username']));


    if ($str_len1 < 6)
    {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "Registration Failed. Unable to add $username to the database!";
        // exit(); using this completely erases the form even after refreshing the page.
    }

    if ($password == $password2) {
    //md5 hashed password for basic security.
    $password = md5($password);
    $sql = "
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
    SET ANSI_PADDING ON
    exec dnmembership.dbo.__NX__CreateAccount '$username','$password','$email'
    ";
    sqlsrv_query ($mysqli, $sql);

    $_SESSION['message'] = "Registration Successful. Added $username to the database!";
    header("location: welcome.php");


}else{
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Registration error. Try a valid username, password, or email.";

    }

    }

?>
```

Comment: 1st of all, put `session_start()` right before the `include_once 'config.php'` tag at the top. Session start should always be at the top of every page without any line spaces. Rest, I am looking at your code.

Comment: Fixing that up right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your code is quite messy. I have tried to clean it up; please use my code as an example and try to practice writing clean code.

Second, never use `$_SESSION['']` to declare a message. The better is to use simple `echo`. Even better, I added a function.

Exit() function Method:

```
session_start();
include('config.php');

// For error or success messages place the following functions in your functions.php file and include the file here.
// The following functions are based on bootstrap classes for error and success message. If you are not using bootstrap you can stylize your own.

function alertSuccess($msg){
  $alert = "<div class='alert alert-success'>".$msg."</div>";
  return $alert;
}

function alertError($msg){
  $alert = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>".$msg."</div>";
  return $alert;
}

function alertInfo($msg){
  $alert = "<div class='alert alert-info'>".$msg."</div>";
  return $alert;
}


// Storing Form Inputs
$username = (!empty($_POST['username']))?mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['username']):null;
$email = (!empty($_POST['email']))?mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['email']):null;
$password = (!empty($_POST['password']))?$_POST['password']:null;
$password2 = (!empty($_POST['confirmpassword']))?$_POST['confirmpassword']:null;

if(isset($_POST['register'])) {
  // Set "Creating Account" message. This is unnecessary but if you want it then okay.
  echo alertInfo("Initiating Account Creation...");

  // If username is null then rest of the code will not be executed
  if($username == null){
    echo alertError("Invalid username!");
    exit();
  }

  // If password is not equal then rest of the code will not be executed
  if($password != $password2){
    echo alertError("Password mismatch");
    exit();
  }

  // If username is less than 6 characters long then rest of the code will not be executed
  if(strlen($username) < 6){
    echo alertError("Username must contain at least 6 characters.");
    exit();
  }

  // All checks done already (including password check). Now process the query.
  $password = md5($password);
  $sql = "SET ANSI_NULLS ON
          SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
          SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
          SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
          SET ANSI_PADDING ON
          exec dnmembership.dbo.__NX__CreateAccount '$username','$password','$email'
          ";

  if(sqlsrv_query($mysqli, $sql)){
    echo alertSuccess("Registration Successful! Please wait....");
    header("Location: welcome.php");
    exit();
  }else{
    echo alertError("Sorry, something went wrong! Please refresh the page and try again.");
  }
}
```

If...Else Function method: Same can be achieved using If...Else method too.

```
if($username == null){
  echo alertError("Invalid username!");
}else if($password != $password2){
  echo alertError("Password mismatch");
}else if(strlen($username) < 6){
  echo alertError("Username must contain at least 6 characters.");
}else{
  // All checks done already (including password check). Now process the query.
  $password = md5($password);
  $sql = "SET ANSI_NULLS ON
          SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
          SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
          SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
          SET ANSI_PADDING ON
          exec dnmembership.dbo.__NX__CreateAccount '$username','$password','$email'
          ";

  if(sqlsrv_query($mysqli, $sql)){
    echo alertError("Registration Successful! Please wait....");
    header("Location: welcome.php");
    exit();
  }else{
    echo alertError("Sorry, something went wrong! Please refresh the page and try again.");
  }
}
```

Use any method you are comfortable with. Both are perfect.

Note that I don't know exactly how to work in SQL SERVER and therefore, I did not look into your `$sql` part. Rest is 100% correct. If you were using PDO I would have checked the SQL too. Please confirm from a right person that you are using correct SQL for your task.

Also, previously, one reason for your code not working might be that the username input might be empty or in simple words the PHP did not receive the form input for username. Hence, I added a check for username to be null as well. If it returns "Invalid username!" then check your form field `name=""` part for username field.

Also note that in your code `$_SESSION['message']` is declared on the top of the page while `session_start()` is declared below. Now tell me how will `$_SESSION['message']` will recognize if there is a session started or not? Unless you start a session you cannot declare `$_SESSION` variables. It will result in an error. Hence, this is the reason why I asked you to declare `session_start()` at the top of the page which is a required and valid PHP practice.